# R create new folders in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, working-directory

I have 10 raster files. What I am trying to do is this:

1) Read the first raster in R (a raster file)

2) save that file in a folder (create the folder within the loop)

3) read the second raster file again

4) save that file in a new folder (also created within the loop)

5) keep repeating 10 times

Here is what I manage to do:

```
for (i in 1:10){
    dir.create(paste0("Run",i))      #this creates a new folder called Run[i] where I will save the raster
    setwd(paste0("Run",i))           # this makes the Run[i] my working directory so that my first raster is saved in Run[i]
    moist<-raster(paste0("R://moist_tif/ind_moist",i,".tif"))      # this reads in my raster moist[i]
    writeRaster(moist,"moist.tif")    # this saves my raster  in folder Run[i]
```

As you might notice when the loop moves to `i+1`, the new folder `Run[i+1]` is created within `Run[i]` which I do not want. I want to create separate folder for `Run[i+1]` rather than folders within folders. Hope I wrote the question clearly. Thank you for your help.

Regards

Comment: (incomplete/untested) I think you need something like `setwd(paste0("../Run",i))` -- although you'll have to be careful the first time through the loop since you won't be within a subdirectory at that point ...

Comment: You problem exists because you change your working directory. Depending on your system, you could try something like `dir.create(sprintf(".\\run%i\\",i))` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's your logic.  If you change directories, you *also need to change back*.

Here is an improved version:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    newdir <- paste0("Run",i)
    dir.create(newdir)      # should test for error
    cwd <- getwd()          # CURRENT dir
    setwd(newdir) 
    moist<-raster(paste0("R://moist_tif/ind_moist",i,".tif"))  
    writeRaster(moist,"moist.tif") 
    setwd(cwd)
}
```